# SQLite C# / Insert Command adds no data into the database

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-insert

I've got a problem resolving my SQLite Database issue.

As the title says, I'm "simply" trying to add some data into a particular table of the database file using SQLite - with the Microsoft.Data.SQLite package.

The code is executed without any errors and even the SQL-Statement execution returns that one row altered. But when I take a look into the db with the db-browser the "inserted" row, simply isn't there at all. This is the code executed:

```
            SqliteConnectionStringBuilder _sqlconsb = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder();
        _sqlconsb.DataSource = _SqliteDatabase;
        _sqlconsb.Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWrite;
        SqliteConnection _sqlconn = new SqliteConnection(_sqlconsb.ConnectionString);
        _sqlconn.Open();

        SqliteCommand _sqlcmd = _sqlconn.CreateCommand();
        _sqlcmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Mediatypes (Name, Type) VALUES ('Hurrey-1', 'i')";
        int _numInsert = _sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _sqlconn.Close();
        return _numInsert;
```

I created a complete new WPF-Application with some buttons and executed the same piece of code in that new app. There it also executes without any issues and the data is indeed added to the db file, which I again checked with the db browser.

I've got no idea, with this particular code adds the new row of data in the test app, but does'nt do it's job in my app. I'm also complete lost in further debbuging this issue, because it's executed without any issues.

One more point to consider, I've other methods in my app which are able to add data successfully to the database into other tables. So i think it sholdn't be the database file itself nor the MS.Data.SQLite package in my solution.

I hope there's anyone out there who's able to point me into the right direction to get this debbuged and or solved ...!

Comment: Sounds obvious but have you checked your connection string is pointing to the correct file? Do the other methods in your app (that are working) use the same connection code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes _SqliteDatabase is a string which contains the DB-File path and is used by all of the methods.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio may be copying it to the build location, so you might not be looking at the same copy

Comment: I have searched the entire project folder, but there is no additional DB file. I also find the changes from the working method in the original DB file. Therefore, I suspect that this is not the reason.